# how to get the exactly the rest when using rand() in hive SQL

Tags: sql, select, random, subquery, hiveql

I wanna split my table into 2 set. one for 5% random selection and the rest is 95%.

```
create table cg_table 
from
(select *
from base_table
where partition = '20210615'
and rand() <= 0.05
distribute by rand()
sort by rand()
)
```

this is the 5% of random selection and I wanna create a rule_table with 95% of the rest of base_table (base_table - cg_table)
pls help me, bros!!!

6/8/2021 I did solved my probs. share with you guys

```
-- create a randomly selected table from base_table
create table if not exists cg_table
from 
(
    select * from base_table
    where rand()<= 0.05
    distribute by rand()
    sort by rand()
)
-- take the rest of base_table (95%) as rule_table
create table if not exists rule_table
from
(
    select a.*
    from base_table a
    left join cg_table b
    on a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name
    where b.id is null
)
```

Comment: Try using where not in.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. maybe my queries is not right. can you share your queries to me, pls?

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data.  Of particular interest is the primary key or unique keys for the table.

Comment: I find a better way to solve this. base_table left join cg_table where cg_table.keys is null. :D